# Quickie: is GetWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDPREV) the correct way to get what would be the hWndInsertAfter in a SetWindowPos()?

Tags: winapi

Here's a quick and simple question; I just want to check that I'm doing this right. This is indeed for a framework/wrapper library.

Let's say I have two windows `A` and `B` and `SetWindowPos(B, A, ...)`. I want to insert `C` between `A` and `B`. I only have `B`'s handle, let's say because `A` is in another layout container, and I want to issue a `SetWindoPos(C, something, ...)` such that the effect would be `SetWindowPos(C, A, ...); SetWindowPos(B, C, ...)`.

My intuition tells me the correct way to get `A` back would be `GetWindow(B, GW_HWNDPREV)`. Am I correct, or do I want `GW_HWNDNEXT` instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that I read you correctly then A is above B in the z-order. That is, A precedes B.

In that case `GetWindow(B, GW_HWNDPREV)` is the window you need to pass to `SetWindowPos` as `hWndInsertAfter`.

Comment: Thanks. Part of the confusion is the use of all these different words (after, next, precedes, above), but I also based my intuition on those, so I guess I've got a good handle on how it works now :/